# Can $f$ be extended to a continuous function from $S$ to $\Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $S = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid -1 \leq x \leq 1 \text{ and } {-1} \leq y \leq 1\}$

and $T = S - (0,0)$  and $f$ be a continuous function from $T$ to  $\Bbb R$,

then how can I disprove or prove that  $f$ can be extended to a continuous function from $S$ to $\Bbb R$?

Can anyone  please help me out?

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{before: } & S = [(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 | -1 \leq x \leq 1 \ and -1 \leq y \leq 1] \\ \\ \text{after: } & S = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid -1 \leq x \leq 1 \text{ and } {-1} \leq y \leq 1\} \end{align} $$ Note the use of \mid and \text{} and of $\{\text{curly braces}\}$. Note that the vertical slash is spaced differently, and the word "and" looks different. And see if you can spot the reason why I enclosed the second $-1$ in braces but not the first one. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** take $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.